# PHP Firebird API: php_interbase or PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

We've been using PDO for 2 years in new scripts to connect to our MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite databases.

We're now starting a project in which we'll need to read (and maybe a few simple UPDATE's) a Firebird 2.5 database file. I'd like to use PDO since we already use that and it will be less of a transition. However the [PDO_FIREBIRD PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_FIREBIRD) package seems to be last updated in 2006.

So my question is: is it better to use the PDO Firebird driver or the php_interbase API for a new project? I.e. is the PDO Firebird driver production worthy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDO Firebird is stable if you use it from main repository of PHP 
You should use the the extension that comes with Php not the PECL one
Here is the PDO health status from last Year http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=6619
Many bugs are fixed from then so you can just try it and abuse it.
The version from PECL **is not** updated for many years but i will take care of it soon https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58824

Of course the php_ibase api is much older and well tested in production systems for years (from the old times of php3 ~ 1998)